# Deciding which redux container to make API calls from

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

[image: Redux Container Components]

In the example component tree, Component C and E both require the same data. This data is fetched from an API call which is triggered via dispatching an action.

My question is, **where should this dispatching of the fetch action occur?**

It could occur in the `componentWillMount()` (via `mapDispatchToProps()`) method of the first mutual parent component, Component B in this case. The problem with this is that component B now has an intimate knowledge of the data it's children require and I can no longer re-use Component C or E without some higher-order component.

Alternatively it could occur in `componentWillMount()` (again, via `mapDispatchToProps()`) of both Component C and E, potentially using a debounce on the action creation (helper libs available). My concern with this is that now Component C and E have some knowledge that they exist on the same page as each other otherwise they wouldn't debounce. Worse still, if Component C appears on another page without Component E then it is unnecessarily debouncing an action.

Does anybody know of a cleaner pattern for fetching data to be used by multiple child components?

Comment: I think using containers will solve your problem. Ideally I am guessing that a component should only take the input and render them. It shouldn't matter to component how this data is fetched. Containers should take care of that. I think in this case Container B will fetch the data and pass it onto both Component C and E. Since Components C and E will just take the data as input and render them, they can be used in other places. I am still getting started with React. So take it with a pinch of salt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to have both components call the same thunk action creator, which should check to see if the request actually needs to be made.  It might look something like this:

```
function loadSomeDataIfNeeded() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const state = getState();

        if(!dataAlreadyLoaded(state) && !currentlyFetchingData(state)) {
            dispatch(startFetchingData())

            fetchData()
                .then(response => {
                    dispatch(dataFetched(response));
                });
        }    
    }
}
```

So, track a "are we fetching right now?" value in your state, and also have logic to figure out if the data has already been loaded.  That way, you can call the thunk multiple times and only actually have it fetch once.